# webpack not creating folder/directory

Tags: webpack

Here's my webpack.config.js code

```
module.exports = {
    entry: "./app/assets/scripts/App.js",
    output: {
        path: "/C/Users/noob/Documents/jay/Sites/travel-site/app/temp/scripts",
        filename: "App.js"
    }
}
```

Here's the webpack output. Problem is it's not creating scripts folder and the App.js file under temp directory
[image: webpack output]

Upon editing the path name to path.resolve here's the error
[image]

Comment: try `c:/Users/[...]` ?

Answer (score 1):

Using an absolute path written by hand is fragile because if you decide to move the directory of your project, you'll still output to the old location. Additionally, paths on Windows are a whole different story. You're better off using the Node.js built-in [`path` module](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html), which creates the correct path for your operating system. To create an absolute path you can use [`path.resolve`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_resolve_paths).

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: "./app/assets/scripts/App.js",
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "app/temp/scripts"),
        filename: "App.js"
    }
}
```

`__dirname` is the directory of the currently executed file (your webpack config).

With this configuration you will always output to the directory `./app/temp/scripts/` relative to your project, no matter where the project is located.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I was following a tutorial where the tutor type something like this path: "app/temp/scripts" --- which gave me an error of something like "____ is not an absolute path." So I decided with that line of code. Thanks. I'll try your code when I get home. I hope it creates the folder and file I want it to create.

Comment: Michael, the code you provided gives me an error. Pls see updated picture above. Thank you!!

Comment: @Hiei you forgot to import `path`, the first line in the posted code.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with this line of codes

```
module.exports = {
    entry: "./app/assets/scripts/App.js",
    output: {
        path: __dirname +  "/app/temp/scripts",
        filename: "App.js"
    }
}
```